# Searching for pages in my site

Tags: html, search

I have a html site I made at work for local use only it meets our requierments howver now I have a large number of pages (174 and growing) and I wanted to make a search function which will apear on the home page and search for the text enterd if found open my page if not redirect to a page stating not found.

The Nicety is that if I googel online all I get is how to build search engines or other non relative things.

dose anybody thus here know how to search the contents of a textbox and if the text matches a site page name that it is then opend?

Comment: Sounds easy, do you use any server side programming language too?

Comment: I normaly just program ussing batch and vb.net so any html or internet programming related stuff is not my home turf I have got golive to build sites but no tutorials mutch of what I built is simple notepad stuff (raw typed)

Comment: Basic online tutorials Adobe Golives cs2 also hard to find?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know any of server side programming language?
I guess you are working with only HTML so I would suggest you to learn any server side programming language and visit the following links so you can get the idea how things work.

http://www.codetrip.info/codetrip/104/Web-Development/What-is-the-difference-between-a-static-and-Dynamic-Web-site

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130529053614AAbetfc